# Make IntelliJ label all arguments rather than just String arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arguments

IntelliJ 2017 has a nice feature where it labels the arguments/parameters being passed using the variable’s name from the method declaration. But IntelliJ seems to do this only for textual (`String`) arguments.

In this example, notice how the first there arguments go unlabeled ( a pair `Instant` objects and a `UUID`), while the 4th & 5th arguments of String literals are labeled `summary:` & `detail:`.

[image: screens shot of a line of code with several arguments being passed in a constructor call]

➠ Why only some arguments rather than all arguments? The logic escapes me.

➠ Is there someway to make IntelliJ display labels for all the arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter hints are configurable in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `General` | `Appearance`, **Show parameter name hints** -> **Configure**:

[image: show hints]

They are intentionally disabled for some basic methods where they will only pollute the editor (like getters, setters, equals, printing and logging):

[image: configure hints]

For your specific case enable the **Show for non-literals in case of multiple params with the same type** option.

Comment: I think the specific configuration which is preventing the OP's `Instant` and `UUID` parameters from being hinted is: "Show for non-literals in case of multiple params with the same type".

Comment: This gets me closer. More arguments are labeled, but **only where more than one argument shares a data type**. After using Objective-C, labeling all arguments is so obviously useful that I do not understand the reluctance to just label them all here in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4):

Go to:

- `Editor > General > Appearance > Show parameter name hints`

Click `Configure` then tick:

- `Show for non-literals in case of multiple params with the same type`

And you'll see hints for the repeated usages of `UUID` and `Instance`, here's an example screenshot:

[image]

In answer to your specific questions:

> Why only some arguments rather than all arguments? The logic escapes me.

IntelliJ is suppressing hints for the for the repeated usages of `UUID` and `Instance`.

> Is there someway to make IntelliJ display labels for all the arguments?

You can control how IntelliJ hints by using `Editor > General > Appearance > Show parameter name hints > Configure`