# IntelliJ/WebStorm: Turn off parameter hints for certain files/methods

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm currently developing a unit test with Jasmine and I am on the newest version of WebStorm, so I have parameter hints enabled, which is a very nice feature.
However, for obvious code, it is rather annoying, so I was wondering if it's possible to turn parameter hints off for certain files and/or methods.

You can see my problem here:

[image: -]

Comment: You can configure methods to ignore like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45806412/104891). Does it help?

Comment: I think OP wanted to disable it for a specific method (at least it's what I came here looking for) - e.g., with an annotation - but thanks for pointing out the generic setting!

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106115/how-to-turn-off-parameter-name-hints-for-code-region-in-intellij-idea