# How to turn off parameter name hints for code region in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, parameters, inlay-hints

I have a chunk of code where I didn't want to see hints of parameter names.

I know there is a comment for turning off code formatting for a chunk of code (`//@formatter:off`), but I can't find something similar for parameter names hints.

There's only local setting for blacklisting methods:

[image]

But I don't want anyone to see parameters hint for my chunk of code.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it for the code range, only for certain methods. Feature request [would be welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).

Comment: Yeah, I did it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246673