# How to add parameter label in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-14

I just started using IntelliJ and while creating my first class and method I noticed something. When I wrote `GomokuClient(4000);` to call on a class from a imported library I of course got a error for the code not being complete, so I pressed the little red bulb to see the issue, and I selected the recommended fix. The fix looked like this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering, how do I write the `portNumber:`label in the parameter myself for other methods. Looked really nice and very helpful, and I'd like to know how to do this myself.

thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix done by the IDE was not about setting parameter label, but instead adding the new() for ensuring the constructor call.

What you additionally see there is a feature of IntelliJ to show method's parameter hints/labels for easy understanding (readability) of the code. You can read more about parameter hints here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/viewing-method-parameter-information.html.

Comment: I see, thanks! is there a way to turn it on for normal Objects/Variables too? would be very helpful. I know you can do this in Python, but don't know about java.

Comment: @TheBigChung, I couldn't quite get what you want to be done with the objects/variables. The *parameter* hints are applicable for methods, which clarifies what value corresponds to which argument.

Comment: Exactly, is there a way to make it so that a label appears all the time for methods?

Comment: @TheBigChung - As far as I have seen, the parameter hint/label does appear all the time for methods everywhere. I don't know why you find it otherwise!

Comment: like this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806316/make-intellij-label-all-arguments-rather-than-just-string-arguments. Only issue is that it was posted 4 years ago and the settings don't look the same.

Comment: @TheBigChung - In my experience, the hints are visible for all parameters in IntelliJ IDEA. Not sure why you're finding it otherwise! Do you have an old IDE, or do you have the settings configured as shown there? Could you share which other objects/values aren't shown as hints, along with the relevant IDE version and corresponding settings.